# Get Duplicated Count Without Removing

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I am trying to get duplicate counts but without actually removing duplicates.
I tried using `GROUP BY id` and then `COUNT(id)` but it removes all duplicate entries.
Is there any way to not remove duplicates?

The table looks like this:

```
ID1   ID2    Value
1     2      someval
1     3      someval
1     4      someval
2     3      someval
2     1      someval
3     1      someval
4     1      someval
```

I am trying to get this:

```
ID1   ID2    Value    COUNT
1     2      someval  3
1     3      someval  3
1     4      someval  3
2     3      someval  2
2     1      someval  2
3     1      someval  1
4     1      someval  1
```

I used this:

```
SELECT ID1, ID2, Value, COUNT(ID1) FROM table GROUP BY ID1;
```

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: I am actually querying this table from a nested select query. So I guess there is no PRIMARY KEY ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of way doing this is to have a separate query for the count and join on it:

```
SELECT t.id1, t.id2, t.value, cnt
FROM   my_table t
JOIN   (SELECT   id1, count(*) AS cnt
        FROM     my_table
        GROUP BY id1) c ON t.id1 = c.id1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a correlated subquery in MySQL;

```
select id1, id2, value,
       (select count(*) from table t2 where t2.id1 = t.id1) as count
from table t;
```

Answer (score 1):

If performance is an issue then an uncorrelated subquery will likely be orders of magnitude faster than a correlated one...

```
SELECT x.* 
     , cnt 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT id1,COUNT(*) cnt FROM my_table GROUP BY id1) y 
    ON y.id1 = x.id1;
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this :

```
SELECT YourColumn, COUNT(*) TotalCount
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY YourColumn
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: Oh sorry I was mistaken. It actually prunes out some values... I am trying other solutions but thank you anyways...